# Apache rewrite rule (url rewriting)

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, apache2

How can make a url rewriting for example, I want my to look like

```
www.myurl.com/study-abroad/what/ever/
```

If I type

```
www.myurl.com/studyabroad/what/ever/
```

The idea is to have study-abroad instead of studyabroad

Comment: dont forget that if you change a url that Google knows about you are going to see a dip in your rankings. Over time you will get most of it back but not 100%

Comment: Actually, my client website has the dash ie
/study-abroad, so he want to replace studyabroad to study-abroad all time

Comment: I just noticed you've unaccepted my answer.  However, as things currently stand, my answer will work, and aefxx's won't. With respect to aefxx, I think he was working on a different interpretation of your question (perhaps an earlier wording); and this can be solved with `mod_rewrite`, but not with what is presently in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done if you know in advance with how many dashes per URL you'd be confronted:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Replacing a single dash, e.g. example.com/study-abroad/what/ever
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ $1$2 [L]

# Replacing two dashes, e.g. example.com/study-abroad/what-ever
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ $1$2$3 [L]
```

... and so forth. May I add, though, that this is broken by design and you should reconsider your approach.

Regards

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I want the url to have the -
ie study-abroad all the time.

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple example I would use `mod_alias` Redirects rather than `mod_rewrite`. Example:

```
Redirect permanent /studyabroad http://www.myurl.com/study-abroad
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect for the full documentation.

You need to put this (or a similar) snippet into an Apache configuration file: if enabled (and if you have appropriate permissions), this might be `.htaccess` in your website's directory.  Or, you could modify the master Apache config. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html for information about Apache configuration files.

(edited to invert the mapping: adding a dash instead of removing it)